VSCode. venv - входит в виртуальное окружение, но не входит
Переустанавливал систему, естественно пришлось переустановить и VSCode - все настройки синхронизировались. В систему поставил 2 версии python: 3.9.13 и 3.12.4. Проект на Django, есть виртуальное окружение (папка .venv). Установил ещё до этого GitBash, чтобы в IDE появился терминал bash - и он появился. Да практически всё отлично - история моих действий видна в терминале на скриншоте.  Я не понимаю что происходит - я захожу в виртуальное окружение, появляется префикс, но все команды которые вводятся далее - исполняются не внутри окружения, а внутри системы. pip не видит модулей, а команда where python выдает интерпретаторы в системе, а не в виртуальном окружении. Я не понимаю в чем дело.

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Нельзя просто так взять и перенести виртуальное окружение с одной учетки/компа на другую учетку/комп. Потому что в самом виртуальном окружении путь до интерпретатора, да и вообще все настройки, будут отличаться от того, как это сделано на другом компе с другой учеткой.
Я разгадал тайну века буквально через две минуты, после того, как решил ещё поисследовать виртуальное окружение.
Мораль: сперва разберитесь как работает виртуальное окружение, правда.
Правильное решение в моей ситуации: не переносить виртуальное окружение при переустановке системы, а создать его с нуля, и установить все необходимые зависимости туда.
